# Does a router have host priority over a switch/computer?

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-ios

I have a router, switch and computer in a network.

Does the host ip address have an order?

Example:

I have the host addresses: 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3
What address does the router get, or does it not matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router uses the address that it is assigned, either by you/the administrator or by the DHCP server.

It doesn't matter which device uses a certain address, only that the connected nodes all use addresses from the same subnet, e.g. 10.0.0.0/24 for 10.0.0.1 through 10.0.0.254. The end nodes also need to know which gateway to use (e.g. 10.0.0.1 as the default gateway).